# The executeJavaScript() in htmlunit not working for me

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I want to login in a page with the javascript Command but after i used the `executeJavaScript()` the last page content still show for me
 with `checkLogin(9143088043,123456,-1,false)`  command the page should be connect and show a new page

```
         final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
         final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://10.254.1.4:90/login.aspx?tt=1");

         String javaScriptCode = "checkLogin(9143088043,123456,-1,false);";


         ScriptResult r= page1.executeJavaScript(javaScriptCode);

         HtmlPage page2=(HtmlPage) r.getNewPage();

         System.out.println(page2.getWebResponse().getContentAsString()); //print the last page content
```

this error in command show for me

```
run:
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:16 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:17 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Invalid selector: *:x).] sourceName=[http://10.254.1.4:90/Script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js] line=[4] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:17 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:17 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:17 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:17 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:17 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:18 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:18 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:18 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:18 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:18 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:18 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:18 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:18 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:18 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:19 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/login.css' [3:1] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "@font-face". Was expecting one of: <S>, <LBRACE>, <COMMA>.)
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:19 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/login.css' [3:1] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:19 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/responsive.css' [1:2] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, <LBRACE>, ".", ":", "[", <COMMA>, <HASH>, <S>.)
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:19 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/responsive.css' [1:2] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:20 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:23 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Invalid selector: *:x).] sourceName=[http://10.254.1.4:90/Script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js] line=[4] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:23 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:23 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:23 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/PortalStyle.css?ver=1.0' [188:32] Invalid color "#00000".
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/PortalStyle.css?ver=1.0' [200:32] Invalid color "#00000".
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/ExtraStyle.css' [3:1] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "@font-face". Was expecting one of: <S>, <LBRACE>, <COMMA>.)
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/ExtraStyle.css' [3:1] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/ExtraStyle.css' [335:23] Invalid color "#0000".
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/stylesGrid.css' [61:27] Error in pseudo class or element. (Invalid token ")". Was expecting one of: <S>, <NUMBER>, <IDENT>, <STRING>, "-", <PLUS>, <DIMENSION>.)
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/stylesGrid.css' [61:27] Ignoring the whole rule.
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/ticker-style.css' [51:6] Error in declaration. (Invalid token ";". Was expecting one of: <S>, ":".)
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/Site.css' [3:1] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "@font-face". Was expecting one of: <S>, <LBRACE>, <COMMA>.)
Oct 29, 2015 2:45:24 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://10.254.1.4:90/Css/Site.css' [3:1] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 19 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it should remove the logs by HtmlUnit:

```
LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);

client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

//(your code)
```